How to synchronize two or more graphics with convertFromPixel in same echarts.instance?
I have two dot graphics (scatter) and I need to move the mouse (mousemove) over one of them and pass the tooltip effect to the other. That is, when I move the mouse over series[0], the tooltip must also appear in series[1] and vice versa. I tried synchronizing the charts with chartUSe.getZr().on(...) but I couldn't get it to work. Also, it wouldn't be interesting to use echarts.connect to do this, as I need the charts to be in the same instance.
Code:


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    // system
    const chartSystem = () => {

        const dfInit = () => {
            
            const groups = ['group1', 'group2', 'group3'];

            const data = [];

            for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                data.push(
                    [
                        (Math.random() * 101) | 0,
                        (Math.random() * 101) | 0,
                        groups[(Math.random() * groups.length) | 0]
                    ]
                )
            }
            return data;
        }

        return {
            "source": {
                "first": dfInit()
            }
        };

    }

    // send
    let pullDataset = [];

    const chartSend = () => {

        const { first } = chartSystem().source;

        pullDataset.push(
            {
                source: [
                    ["x1", "x2", "groups"],
                    ...first
                ]
            }
        )

    }

    chartSend();

    // frames
    const chartUse = echarts.init(document.getElementsByClassName('chart')[0]);

    function chartFrameSwitch0 () {

        const title0 = [
            {
                text: "convertFromPixel in same instance (chartUse)",
                left: 'center',
                textStyle: {
                    fontSize: 30,
                    color: "#242832"
                }
            }
        ];

        const tooltip0 = {
            trigger: "axis"
        };

        const grid0 = [
            {
                left: '5%',
                top: '12%',
                width: '40%',
                height: '35%'
            },
            {
                right: '5%',
                top: '12%',
                width: '40%',
                height: '35%'
            }
        ];

        const xAxis0 = [
            {
                type: 'value',
                gridIndex: 0
            },
            {
                type: 'value',
                gridIndex: 1
            }
        ];

        const yAxis0 = [
            {
                type: 'value',
                gridIndex: 0
            },
            {
                type: 'value',
                gridIndex: 1
            }
        ];

        const series0 = [
            {
                type: 'scatter',
                datasetIndex: 0,
                xAxisIndex: 0,
                yAxisIndex: 0,
                encode: {
                    x: 0,
                    y: 1
                }
            },
            {
                type: 'scatter',
                datasetIndex: 0,
                xAxisIndex: 1,
                yAxisIndex: 1,
                encode: {
                    x: 0,
                    y: 1
                }
            }
        ];

        const option = {
            title: title0,
            tooltip: tooltip0,
            grid: grid0,
            dataset: [pullDataset[0]],
            xAxis: xAxis0,
            yAxis: yAxis0,
            series: series0
        };

        chartUse.setOption(option);

    }

    chartFrameSwitch0();

    // Charts synchronize 
    chartUse.getZr().on('mousemove', function(params) {

        // Catch mousemove event
        let pointInGrid = [params.offsetX, params.offsetY];

        // series 0 interaction
        if (params.seriesIndex === 0) {

            let index = chartUse.convertFromPixel({ seriesIndex: 0 }, pointInGrid)[0];

            // Checks if the index is within the data range
            if (index >= 0 && index < pullDataset[0].source.length) {

                chartUse.dispatchAction({
                    type: 'showTip',
                    seriesIndex: 1,
                    dataIndex: index
                });

            }

        } 
        
        // series 1 interaction
        else if (params.seriesIndex === 1) {

            let index = chartUse.convertFromPixel({ seriesIndex: 1 }, pointInGrid)[0];

            // Checks if the index is within the data range
            if (index >= 0 && index < pullDataset[0].source.length) {

                chartUse.dispatchAction({
                    type: 'showTip',
                    seriesIndex: 0,
                    dataIndex: index
                });

            }

        }
        
    });


});
<head>
    <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.5.0/dist/echarts.min.js'></script>
</head>
    
<div class='chart' style='width: 100%; height: 100vh;'></div>



EDIT
I didn't know the component type axisPointer existed, it makes the connection between the graphics I need to connect. The problem, however, lies in separating the tooltips. I need them to correspond to your graphic. In other words, instead of being together, they need to “wander” around each chart. In other words, one tooltip for xAxis[0] and another for xAxis[1].
This is the code with axisPointer:


<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.5.0/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="chart" style="width: 100%; height: 100vh"></div>

<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    // system
    const chartSystem = () => {
      const dfInit = () => {
        const groups = ["group1", "group2", "group3"]

        const data = []

        for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
          data.push([
            (Math.random() * 101) | 0,
            (Math.random() * 101) | 0,
            groups[(Math.random() * groups.length) | 0],
          ])
        }
        return data
      }

      return {
        source: {
          first: dfInit(),
        },
      }
    }

    // send
    let pullDataset = []

    const chartSend = () => {
      const { first } = chartSystem().source

      pullDataset.push({
        source: [["x1", "x2", "groups"], ...first],
      })
    }

    chartSend()

    // frames
    const chartUse = echarts.init(document.getElementsByClassName("chart")[0])

    function chartFrameSwitch0() {
      const title0 = [
        {
          text: "Use axisPointer to synchronize",
          left: "center",
          textStyle: {
            fontSize: 30,
            color: "#242832",
          },
        },
      ]

      const tooltip0 = {
        trigger: "axis",
        axisPointer: {
          lineStyle: {
            color: "#000",
          },
        },
      }

      const axisPointer0 = {
        triggerTooltip: false,
        link: [
          {
            xAxisIndex: [0, 1]
          }
        ],
      }

      const grid0 = [
        {
          left: "5%",
          top: "12%",
          width: "40%",
          height: "35%",
        },
        {
          right: "5%",
          top: "12%",
          width: "40%",
          height: "35%",
        },
      ]

      const xAxis0 = [
        {
          type: "value",
          gridIndex: 0,
        },
        {
          type: "value",
          gridIndex: 1,
        },
      ]

      const yAxis0 = [
        {
          type: "value",
          gridIndex: 0,
        },
        {
          type: "value",
          gridIndex: 1,
        },
      ]

      const series0 = [
        {
          type: "scatter",
          datasetIndex: 0,
          xAxisIndex: 0,
          yAxisIndex: 0,
          encode: {
            x: 0,
            y: 1,
          },
        },
        {
          type: "scatter",
          datasetIndex: 0,
          xAxisIndex: 1,
          yAxisIndex: 1,
          encode: {
            x: 0,
            y: 1,
          },
        },
      ]

      const option = {
        title: title0,
        tooltip: tooltip0,
        axisPointer: axisPointer0,
        grid: grid0,
        dataset: [pullDataset[0]],
        xAxis: xAxis0,
        yAxis: yAxis0,
        series: series0,
      }

      chartUse.setOption(option)
    }

    chartFrameSwitch0();

  })
</script>





I don't think there's a way on Echart to have more than one tooltip instance for graphic, but i changed your function, so if you want your tooltip to show on the other graph, just click on the circle.
If you just want for one tooltip to show the other graphs info, you can use the formatter option.
If it is really necessary, the tooltip is still created via JS, so you could create your own and just use the transform property to allocate it, just like Echart does: 



document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  // system
  const chartSystem = () => {
    const dfInit = () => {
      const groups = ["group1", "group2", "group3"];

      const data = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        data.push([
          (Math.random() * 101) | 0,
          (Math.random() * 101) | 0,
          groups[(Math.random() * groups.length) | 0],
        ]);
      }
      return data;
    };

    return {
      source: {
        first: dfInit(),
      },
    };
  };

  // send
  let pullDataset = [];

  const chartSend = () => {
    const { first } = chartSystem().source;

    pullDataset.push({
      source: [["x1", "x2", "groups"], ...first],
    });
  };

  chartSend();

  // frames
  const chartUse = echarts.init(document.getElementsByClassName("chart")[0]);

  function chartFrameSwitch0() {
    const title0 = [
      {
        text: "convertFromPixel in same instance (chartUse)",
        left: "center",
        textStyle: {
          fontSize: 30,
          color: "#242832",
        },
      },
    ];

    const tooltip0 = {
      trigger: "axis",
    };

    const grid0 = [
      {
        left: "5%",
        top: "12%",
        width: "40%",
        height: "35%",
      },
      {
        right: "5%",
        top: "12%",
        width: "40%",
        height: "35%",
      },
    ];

    const xAxis0 = [
      {
        type: "value",
        gridIndex: 0,
      },
      {
        type: "value",
        gridIndex: 1,
      },
    ];

    const yAxis0 = [
      {
        type: "value",
        gridIndex: 0,
      },
      {
        type: "value",
        gridIndex: 1,
      },
    ];

    const series0 = [
      {
        type: "scatter",
        datasetIndex: 0,
        xAxisIndex: 0,
        yAxisIndex: 0,
        encode: {
          x: 0,
          y: 1,
        },
      },
      {
        type: "scatter",
        datasetIndex: 0,
        xAxisIndex: 1,
        yAxisIndex: 1,
        encode: {
          x: 0,
          y: 1,
        },
      },
    ];

    const option = {
      title: title0,
      tooltip: tooltip0,
      grid: grid0,
      dataset: [pullDataset[0]],
      xAxis: xAxis0,
      yAxis: yAxis0,
      series: series0,
    };

    chartUse.setOption(option);
  }

  chartFrameSwitch0();

  // Charts synchronize
  chartUse.on("click", function (params) {
    const dataIndex = params.dataIndex;
    const seriesIndex = params.seriesIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;

    if (dataIndex >= 0 && dataIndex < pullDataset[0].source.length) {
      chartUse.dispatchAction({
        type: "showTip",
        seriesIndex: seriesIndex,
        dataIndex: dataIndex,
      });
    }
  });
});
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.5.0/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="chart" style="width: 100%; height: 100vh"></div>



